# Tridion Docs : Can we upload a .fbx file type in Tridion Docs 14 SP2?

Tags: tridion-docs

Just wanted to know if we can upload a `.fbx` file type in Tridion Docs 14 SP2. Is it supported? I couldn't give it a try as currently .fbx file type is not available with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Tridion Docs - OOTB **.fbx** file type extension not available. but it's possible to set up a new Electronic Document Type (EDT) file type using Tridion Docs Webservice API.

Apart from this backend EDT field setup, we also need to add this new EDTFBX file extension to **MetadataConfig.xml** and use Web Client/Web service to set up your new editor template for this type.

Here is the example powershell script to create the new EDT in Tridion Docs server:

```
#autodetect Webservices
$webBaseUrl = Get-ISHDeploymentParameters -Name baseurl -Value
$ishws = Get-ISHDeploymentParameters -Name infosharewswebappname -Value
$webServicesBaseUrl = $webBaseUrl + "/" + $ishws + "/"

$ishMetadata = Set-IshMetadataField -IshSession $ishSession -Name "EDT-CANDIDATE" -Level "none" -Value "fbx" `
                           | Set-IshMetadataField -IshSession $ishSession -Name "EDT-FILE-EXTENSION" -Level "none" -Value "fbx" `
                           | Set-IshMetadataField -IshSession $ishSession -Name "EDT-MIME-TYPE" -Level "none" -Value "application/octet-stream"

$createdEDT = Add-IshEDT -IshSession $ishSession -Name "FBX" -Metadata $ishMetadata
$id = $createdEDT.IshRef
```

Here you can find some of the document references:

- [Adding an image template](https://docs.rws.com/796504/143196/sdl-tridion-docs-14-sp2/adding-an-image-template)
- [How do you add files to a Template-type folder?](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-docs/f/forum/27710/how-do-you-add-files-to-a-template-type-folder/88509#88509)
- [EDT 2.5 Create Webservice API](https://docs.rws.com/955882/290927/tridion-docs-14-sp4/edt-2-5-create)

Comment: Thank you Velmurugan for explanation.